# When to use esc_url, esc_html, esc_attr, and friends?

Tags: theme-development, functions, customization, security

Discovered `esc_url` today while customizing an [_s](http://underscores.me/) theme. I understand what the function does (sanitizes the URL inside), but what I'm unsure of is the scope of its use.

It makes sense to me that if I'm accepting a URL input from a user, that I'd use this. But when I was looking at a function that displayed the entry's meta info ([see it here](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/inc/template-tags.php)...line 129 at the moment), it used `esc_url`, which doesn't make sense to me.

If I'm working on a theme, do I need to be escaping ANY URL that I put in my template files?

Answer (score 4):

Those function are used to produce a valid HTML and not to sanitize input. You should use them anytime you are not 100% sure that what you want to output is a valid HTML for that context.

Should you escape everything? I guess the _s theme people decided that it is better to be safe then sorry, and there is some logic to that.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) says that it should always be used when sanitizing URLs; that's why I thought it was for sanitizing.